# Throttling simulator for WebRTC for Windows

Tags: javascript, webrtc, latency, throttling, low-latency

Since Throttling in Firefox & Chrome doesn't work with WebRTC yet, i'm looking for other solutions.

Need to make latency worse only for one tab in browser or only for one browser.

Netlimiter 4 would be fine, but they still hasn't latency limiting feautre.

Programs without UI aren't good in my case.

Do you know some?

Answer (score 0):

You basically need to throttle UDP packets being sent. This is not possible on browsers.

Checkout [this](https://medium.com/@udayreddy/upd-throttling-for-apps-based-on-webrtc-36dd18b36097) blog for detailed explanation.

Answer (score -2):

I know there is an option in Chrome to throttle network traffic in diffrent cellular or Wifi network. Is this not working for you attaching snap[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WcDDZ.png)

You can check under network tab " No throttling " and change option as per your need.

Comment: As I said up here, throttling in Chrome & Firefox doesnt work with Webrtc. It is in development still

Comment: it is there , please update your chrome to latest ie v58 kindly refer the link( https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/reference#throttling).If you fail and only want to test your web application you can test in chrome canary  else you can use testRTC for simulating so.